# Laravel Lighthouse Config - unable to locate publishable resources

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-lighthouse

I have installed the latest version of Lighthouse into my Laravel 7 app and it's been working fine with the out-of-the-box config. I now want to tweak some settings for better security, so as per [the docs](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/getting-started/configuration.html) I have tried to use the following command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lighthouse-config
```

to publish the config file. But I get the following error:

```
Unable to locate publishable resources.
Publishing complete.
```

No lighthouse.php file is published to the config folder. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just tried it in an example project and it worked just fine.

A simple workaround is to run:

```
cp vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/lighthouse.php config/lighthouse.php
```

Comment: Yeah in the end i just copied it from the Github source. I didn't know if Laravel did some behind-the-scenes config-registering magic or something though.

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel 8 Lighthouse Config:**

just run `php artisan vendor:publish` and choose the class that you want to publish.

it's work for me on **Laravel 8**
[image]